# Powershell. Pull camera attribute to append to file name

Tags: powershell

I had a PowerShell script that works well for a single camera to copy and move images and movies off the camera to two repositories. We are now implementing multiple cameras so i need a way to ensure file names are unique that are being stored on the file share.

Problem is I am not sure how to pull a unique device ID from the camera or the storage device. I have tried to pull EXIF data but it seems this camera is not writing a unique serial on EXIF. So that leaves me with either a drop down/manual input of options to append to a file name, or maybe yyyymmddhhmmss so each file has a very slim chance to be a duplicate.

I want to make this as user friendly as possible since the users are not technically apt.

Thoughts?

```
$todaysDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$destinationFolderArchive = "\\fileserver\1\$todaysDate"
$destinationFolderWorking = "\\fileserver\2\$todaysDate"
$mydrive=(GWmi Win32_LogicalDisk | ?{$_.VolumeName -eq 'CAMERA'} | %{$_.DeviceID})
$IncludeFiles = ("*.jpg","*.avi","*.mpg","*.mov")

if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolderArchive)) {New-Item $destinationFolderArchive -Type Directory}
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolderWorking)) {New-Item $destinationFolderWorking -Type Directory}

Get-ChildItem -Path $mydrive -Recurse -Include $IncludeFiles | Copy-Item -Destination                   
$destinationFolderArchive -verbose
Get-ChildItem -Path $mydrive -Recurse -Include $IncludeFiles  | Move-Item -Destination
$destinationFolderWorking -verbose

Write-Host "The file sync is complete. Press any key to continue."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the simplest thing you can do is use The Scripting Guys' script: `Get-FileMetaData` ([available on the TechNet Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804)). Then you can copy the pics to a temp folder, run the script against that folder, and sort things from there with a `Switch`. This is an example of the data that it will return:

```
Name                  : Gold KATA by Patrick Rochon.jpg
Size                  : 238 KB
Item type             : JPEG image
Date modified         : 8/7/2013 8:20 AM
Date created          : 8/7/2013 8:19 AM
Date accessed         : 8/7/2013 8:19 AM
Attributes            : A
Perceived type        : Image
Owner                 : Domain\TMTech
Kind                  : Picture
Date taken            : ‎4/‎14/‎2013 ‏‎10:38 PM
Tags                  : bulb; kata; led; light art; light painting; long exposure; performance; 
                        photography; dance; martial art
Rating                : Unrated
Authors               : Patrick Rohon
Title                 : The light painting KATA  is the expression of the light we move and create 
                        everyday and  the trace we leave behind.
Subject               : The light painting KATA  is the expression of the light we move and create 
                        everyday and  the trace we leave behind.
Copyright             : Copyright PatrickRochon©2013
Camera model          : NIKON D600
Dimensions            : ‪1200 x 780‬
Camera maker          : NIKON CORPORATION
Program name          : Adobe Photoshop CS5 Macintosh
Computer              : Digital_Ghost (this computer)
Filename              : Gold KATA by Patrick Rochon.jpg
Bit depth             : 24
Horizontal resolution : ‎72 dpi
Width                 : ‎1200 pixels
Vertical resolution   : ‎72 dpi
Height                : ‎780 pixels
Shared                : No
Folder name           : My Pictures
Folder path           : C:\Users\TMTech\My Pictures
Folder                : My Pictures (C:\Users\TMTech)
Path                  : C:\Users\TMTech\My Pictures\Gold KATA by Patrick Rochon.jpg
Type                  : JPEG image
Link status           : Unresolved
EXIF version          : 0230
Exposure bias         : ‎0 step
Exposure program      : Manual
Exposure time         : ‎33 sec.
Flash mode            : No flash, compulsory
ISO speed             : ISO-100
Max aperture          : 0
Metering mode         : Center Weighted Average
Orientation           : Normal
Program mode          : Manual
Saturation            : Low saturation
White balance         : Manual
```

Do you need more help than that?

Comment: The problem becomes the three cameras being used are identical and I am not seeing a unique property per-camera that can be pulled from the EXIF data.

Comment: So... what exactly were you hoping for? This gets all of the extra attributes for you, if what you want isn't here then you don't want to extract something from the files, you would have to have the script prompt for which camera is plugged in or something.

Comment: Hoping for anyone that has come up with creative solutions when say EXIF does not provide unique enough data. I was hoping for maybe a hidden serialization of the camera itself, or some unique identifier of the card.